# how to stop Slide Animation with Basic jQuery Slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, slideshow

I'm using the library [Basic jQuery Slider](http://basic-slider.com/).
I use the same example that is in the page, but there is a moment when I can't handle the animation, because the animation doesn't stop.

How to make the animation stop when it is finished with all the images?